Is it possible to get Syntax Highlighting for Angular/Typescript in Visual Studio 2022
In Visual Studio 2022 developing in C# everything is nice and colored/syntax highlighted.
I am working on a Full-stack app with an Angular frontend and hate having to use VSCode to have nice syntax highlighted text for my angular code.
I've tried searching for Angular extensions or someway to get highlighting thats like VSCode for Angular/VS 2022 but can't seem to find anything.
Everything I search just brings me to VSCode stuff.
So is it possible to achieve this or should I just swallow the pill and use VSCode?

Which Visual Studio 2022 Version do you have?

Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.111.1
